# Tizen 2.2 Software rendering OpenGL engine creation failed

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, rendering, opengl-es-2.0, tizen

I need Some Help in running the Browser on Tizen (I have my Tizen 2.2 build Up & running) , I am trying to run a browser with Software rendering , as I see evas supports multiple engines in Tizen Opengl_x11,Software_x11, etc..,as I dont have Vendor SDK for Hardware rendering right now due to some logical reasons, I want to run my app(browser) with software rendering, Can anyone please guide me how to enable software rendering, does it has to be doen while building the tizen itself ?? , When I run a browser through command prompt I get following Log

> ERR<1442>:ecore_evas ecore_evas_x.c:264 _ecore_evas_x_gl_window_new()
>
> > > evas_engine_info_set() for engine 'opengl_x11' failed.
> > >
> > > ERR<1442>:ecore_evas ecore_evas_x.c:3586 ecore_evas_gl_x11_options_new()
> > >       evas_engine_info_set() init engine 'opengl_x11' failed.
> > >
> > > CRI<1442>:elementary elm_win.c:2620 elm_win_add() OpenGL engine creation
> > >       failed. Trying default.
> > >
> > > CRI<1442>:evas_main main.c:114 evas_debug_magic_wrong() Input object is
> > >       wrong type

*
& browser doesnt comes up...

I am not sure what is missing, Any seniors can provide some pointers in this regard will be very helpful.

PS: My X server is running..

Comment: Hello, maybe you could be a little bit more specific. Do you have a native application or what are you trying to do?

Comment: @ruff1991 - I want to run a App (Browser) with Software Rendering as I see it supports multiple engines like software_x11, opengl_x11 etc.., I want to use Software Rendering , How do i Do that ?

Comment: Maybe check the Tizen developer website forum section. My experience with Tizen goes only as far as porting native applications.